# why firebase/auth Signinwithpopup creates new user instead of returning user does not exist?

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, next.js, google-signin

I am building a web app using Next.js and Node.js-Express backend with MongoDB. I am stuck figuring out how to handle the user authentication with firebase using the `signinwithpopup` method.

consider the following use case , The user is on login page and the user is new or have not created account before. If the user tries to Sign in using the sign in with google button.  It will initiate a sign in process, the sdk will first check if the user already exists on firebase and allows the user to sign in or if the user does not exist it will create a new user on firebase and authenticate the user. When the user is logged in and the app tries to fetch the user data from database the user does not exist on my database.  do you have any solution or advice ?

here is the current `signInWithPopup` implementation

AUTH context

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { signInWithPopup, signOut, onAuthStateChanged, GoogleAuthProvider, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth  } from "../../firebase";
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
import { FirebaseError } from "firebase/app";


interface AuthContextType {
    user: User
    googleSignin: () => void
    emailSignup: (email: string, password: string) => void
    emailSignin: (email: string, password: string) => void
    logOut: () => void
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(null);

export const AuthContextProvider = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const emailSignup = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseError) {
                console.log(e.code)
                console.log(e.message)
            } else {
                console.log(e)
            }

        }  
    }

    const emailSignin = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseError) {
                console.log(e.code)
                console.log(e.message)
            } else {
                console.log(e)
            }

        }
    }

    const googleSignin = () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

        try {
            signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
        
    }

    const logOut = () => {
        signOut(auth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [user])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, googleSignin, emailSignup, emailSignin, logOut}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

usage on sign in page

```
import { UserAuth } from "../../utils/global contexts/AuthContext";
...

//...

 const handleSignin = () => {
    console.log("Signing in with google")
    try {
      googleSignin()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

// ... 

 <button
            onClick={handleSignin}
            className="bg-white text-gray-800 font-bold rounded-md px-3 py-3 border-2 border-gray-900/20 flex gap-2 w-full items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
            <img src="/images/google.png" alt="google" className="h-5 w-5" />
            Google
          </button>
```

I am looking for some expert advice on auth flow design.

Comment: you might show us your code where it doesn't work at first

Comment: I am using ```signInWithPopup```  from firebase sdk "firebase/auth"